# SpriteKit GameScene Rotation Bug

Tags: ios, swift, screen-orientation, device-orientation

I have been having a problem recently with this app which I encountered whilst trying to make the app universal and portrait orientation as well (the previous version was landscape on iPhone only). Now the app will open in portrait and look correct, but it is still in portrait when the device is rotated.

[image: App Error]

This is currently all the code I have for rotating the device (which works):

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
        return .AllButUpsideDown
    } else {
        return .All
    }
}
```

However, this only rotates the device and not the actual GameScene within which my game is contained. If the app is launched from a landscape homescreen, the game will stay in landscape.

For testing purposes, I can quit and relaunch the app from the simulator homescreen and the game will work perfectly again *until the device is rotated*.

***How do I consistently present the GameScene in the correct orientation?***

Comment: you are presenting the `skView` in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillLayoutSubviews` ?

Comment: I use `viewDidLoad`, I tried to switch that to `viewWillLayoutSubviews`. It ran perfectly for maybe half a second and then crashed so I changed it back to `viewDidLoad` again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Good Doug said try setting the skView size.

In code you would load the first scene from the gameViewController like so. (This works if you dont use the scene sks files)

```
    let skView = view as! SKView!
    let scene = StartScene(size: skView.bounds.size)

    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

    skView.presentScene(scene)
```

Also its seems like a very bad idea to make a game run in portrait and landscape, it will cause you so many problems I wouldn't even try.

Comment: I would be fine with it only running in landscape except that I couldn't get it to upload as it said iPad must support all orientations?

Comment: You changed the orientation in targets? You also need to go to your info.Plist  and there the last option is supported orientations for iPad. Remove the 2 portrait or landscape entries, they do not get removed automatically if you change your orientations in Targets.

Comment: That was it! The other `info.Plist` entry I needed to add was `UIRequiresFullScreen` as a `Bool` and set that to `YES`.

Comment: Awesome. I thought that option is on by default., you can also turn this on/off in targets-General right underneath the "HideStatusBar" option.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to make sure that your `SKView` that holds your `SKScene` is set to match the bounds of it's containing frame. You can do this with Autolayout either in InterfaceBuilder or through code.